# Does your Vimeo app need upload access to upload to your own account?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am attempting to use the Vimeo API to upload a video to my own account (I have a PRO account). I have requested upload access and the request is still pending.

When I attempt to get an upload ticket with a request to: http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?method=vimeo.videos.upload.getTicket

I receive the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp generated_in="0.0073" stat="fail">
        <err code="701" expl="The user does not have a PRO account." msg="Cannot upload"/>
</rsp>
```

The request is to my own account, which is a PRO account. Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app page should show you which upload permissions you have been granted.

If it says the request is pending, it means it has not been approved by Vimeo staff yet.
If it says "owner" it means the app owner can upload to their own account.
If it says "PRO", "Plus" or "Basic" it means that users with those subscription levels are able to upload to their own account using your app.

If you think you should be able to upload, and can not, contact Vimeo at vimeo.com/help/contact